# Best practice upload file IIS permission

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web solution which different users from different companies logs on to the same web site, they authenticate against AD.

I use RadControls, and their upload component.

I want to be able to make the users upload documents to their folder on the server. I have granted users which belongs to a particular company full access to the corresponding folder. But I get a access permission error when trying to upload.

What is best practice for something like this?

I use IIS7, and ASP.Net 3.5

Comment: Do you have impersonation enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Paddy probably hit the nail on the head... but if you look at the Event Viewer entry for this exception, you can probably see what user's credentials ASP.NET is actually using to write the file.

BTW... in terms of best practice... You're on the right track.  You didn't mention *where* this directory is located, but it should be OUTSIDE your web root.  Other than that, it's all implementation details... like what do you do for name collisions?